# Highly Recommended References on Harmonic and Stationary Measures

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation

A harmonic or stationary measure is said to be **Regular** if it is **Absolutely Continuous** with respect to **Lebesgue Measure** and **Singular** if it is not. I need to understand the **Regularity and Singularity of Harmonic and Stationary Measures**. Despite saying that, I actually know nothing about these types of measures. Therefore, I am looking for highly recommended references on these concepts (to be more precise, to be able first to understand the concepts of harmonic and stationary measures and then the regularity and singularity of these kinds of measures). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more context in order to get any meaningful answer. Are you interested in group actions? On any specific group actions?

Comment: @JohnB On the one hand, yes, I am really interested in group action. On the other hand, I need to understand the regularity and singularity of these measures so I am first supposed to understand them.

Comment: What brings you there? It's a very specific topic. Anyway, have a look at the book on harmonic functions of Axler, Bourdon and Ramey: https://www.axler.net/HFT.html

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro the title of this book is (Harmonic Function), and I want to read about (Harmonic Measures)?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro there is exactly only one exercise on page $237$ regarding **Harmonic Measure**.

Comment: @JohnB can you play check my question again please?